# Number of divisors excluding set of primes S

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, spoj

Quite much time ago I found task where I was pleased to compute number of divisors (they are primes!) excluding numbers from set S (in other words, set S should only contain divisors of number N, which is easy).
Next I'm doing prime factorization so I receive
$N = p_1^{a_1} \times p_2^{a_2} \times ... \times p_k^{a_k}.$
Next number of divisors D of number N is $(a1+1)(a2+1) ... (ak+1)$
and requires number is $D-|S|$

For example 
we have number N=58
and at beginning 2 elements in the set: $2,3$
2 divides 58, but 3 doesn't so we have only in set 2.
prime factorization of 58 is $2^1+29^1$ so number of divisors D is (1+1)(1+1)=4.
Assume that 58 isn't divisor of 58, so we have 3 divisors.
Finally, our result is$ D-|S|=2$

Today I came up with this solution, but it's too slow approach. Is there any faster?
Thanks for any hints, solutions, Math Friend.
Cheers Chris

P.S there is link to this task: https://www.spoj.pl/problems/HABLU/

EDIT: Having had a look at the link, I'm going to try to restate the problem in a more standard way. You are given a set $S$ of primes, and a positive integer $N$. You are to find out how many divisors $N$ has, not counting those that are multiples of one or more of the primes in $S$.

Comment: If $n = p_1^{a_1} \ldots p_n^{a_n}$ and $S = \{p_{i}\}_{i \in I}$ then I think the number of divisors excluding $S$ is $\prod_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n\} \setminus I} (1+a_i)$ (the product of $(1+a_i)$ excluding values $i \in I$). To compute it, divide $n$ by elements of $S$ as long as you can, then compute the number of divisors of the resulting number.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't notice the line "S only contains primes or 1".

Comment: There is ambiguity. Does $\:p\in S\:$ mean that you wish to exclude all divisors divisible by $\:p\:,\:$ or does it mean to exclude only the divisor $\:p\:$?

Comment: Sorry for lack of explaination.
I want to exclude all divisors which are divisible by $p$ from $S$

Comment: My previous answer still seems applicable to me.  Use your formula $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots $ including only those $a_i$ that correspond to primes not in $S$

Answer (score 4):

If $S$ only has primes, can't you just ignore those primes in the factorization of $N$?.  That is, if $n=210=2*3*5*7$ and $S=\{2,3\}$, isn't the answer $4$, being $\{1,5,7,35\}$?